# Splitting a VARCHAR by length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to split a VARCHAR into multiple rows, according to a predefined "row length".

For example, if the value is: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and the row length is 15, then I need 3 rows, as in:

```
split
---------------
The quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog
```

Comment: I don't see a question here, just a requirement? Please include your current attempt and explain what is not working.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't do this in postgres, but this feels like the wrong platform to perform such a transformation.

Comment: I've tried unnest() but it works with a delimiter, not a fixed length. Sorry for the confusion. For example: unnest(string_to_array('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ' ')) splits into9 separate lines, each one having a word.

Comment: What would the same sentence look like if the length were 13 or 17? Can you break words? What if there's punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

SQL may not be the correct tool for this because I think the look-ahead for line breaks requires recursion.  This will work, but it is more toy than useful:

```
with recursive invars as (
  select 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' as intext, 15 as line_length
), tokens as (
  select words.*, i.line_length, count(*) over () as word_count
    from invars i
         cross join lateral 
           regexp_split_to_table(i.intext, '\W+') with ordinality as words(word, i)
), build as (
  select i, 
         case when length(word) >= line_length then '' else word end as words, 
         case when length(word) >= line_length then word end as break_line
    from tokens 
   where i = 1
  union all
  select c.i, 
         case 
           when length(trim(p.words)||' '||c.word) > c.line_length then c.word
           else trim(p.words)||' '||c.word
         end as words,
         case 
           when length(trim(p.words)||' '||c.word) > c.line_length and length(p.words) > 0 
             then p.words
           when c.i = word_count 
             then trim(p.words)||' '||c.word
         end as break_line
    from tokens c
         join build p on p.i = c.i - 1
)
select row_number() over (order by i), break_line as split
  from build
 where break_line is not null;
```